# PHP - Make PHP function output multiple instances

Tags: php, arrays, function, hyperlink

I have `$tutorial->difficulty` which sometimes has multiple outputs, and for each output that goes into the `breakCommas` function, I need to output a link for each one. Currently with how I have it, when `$tutorial->difficulty` outputs multiple items, it basically clumps them all into a single link. From what I've read I realize you can't have multiple outputs per function. Any ideas how I can separate it to where it outputs multiple links?

PHP

```
function breakCommas($str) {
  return ('<a href="'.str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($str)).'-tutorial">'.$str.'</a>');
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <?=breakCommas($tutorial->difficulty)?>
</div>
```

Comment: _"which sometimes has multiple outputs"_ Meaning what? It contains an array?

Comment: I believe so. I'm a PHP newbie. But yes it outputs multiple text items separated by a comma...like "Beginner,Intermediate,Advanced"

Comment: And in that case it outputs `<a>Beginner,Intermediate,Advanced</a>` instead of what I need: `<a>Beginner</a> <a>Intermediate</a> <a>Advanced</a>`

Comment: Right ok, that's not an array, that's a comma-separated string. First you'll need to split that string into an array (perhaps via the explode() function) and then loop over that array, calling breakCommas() for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I tried this just to test:

`$dfgdfg = explode(",",$tutorial->difficulty);

$coladsfadsors = array($dfgdfg);
foreach ($coladsfadsors as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}`

but it doesn't seem to be putting it into an array properly. Any ideas?

Comment: `explode()` already returns an array, so if you do `array($dfgdfg)` on top of that, you're putting that array inside another array. Take out that second step and just do `$array = explode(",", $tutorial->difficulty));` and then `foreach ($array as $item) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function:

```
function breakCommas($str) {
    $s = explode (",", $str);
    $a = array();
    foreach ($s as $st) {
        $a[] = "<a href=\"".str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($st))."-tutorial\">{$st}</a>";
    }
    return implode("", $a);
}
```